# Selecting only one item from a class

Tags: jquery, asp.net, database, gridview, datatable

I have a GridView that has an `<asp:Label>` in it with ID="Description" and CssClass="dsc". In my C#.net code  behind the aspx file, I have a data table that has the addresses and descriptions from a database, I am populating a Google Map with the Lat/Lng coods that are converted from the address with the little Google Markers. When the marker is clicked, the description for that address pops up above the marker. This is working fine.

Now for the hard part, I am trying to add the same description to each row in the GridView, uniquely. Does that make sense? When a row is clicked (each row will have a title, which is the description from the db), the description needs to open up above the marker in the Google map. Each row in the GridView will have their own description and address.

Here is my code so far:

```
public partial class NEW_controls_RoadsAndBridges : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            getInfo();
        }
    }



    protected void getInfo()
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            ///
            ///Check to see if connection is good
            ///
            string selectString = "SELECT Address, Description, Date, Lat, Long FROM D2_ReportAProblemForm ORDER BY id DESC";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectString, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            BuildScript(dt);
            cmd.Dispose();

            //If successful 
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (SqlException sqle)
        {
            //if error
            // Response.Redirect("ReportAProblemInfo.aspx?info=fail");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.Close();
        }
    }



    private void BuildScript(DataTable tbl)
    {
        String Locations = "";
        String Description = "";
        String Address = "";
        String java = "";
        String java2 = "";
        int n = 0;
        foreach (DataRow r in tbl.Rows)
        {
            string Latitude = r["Long"].ToString();
            string Longitude = r["Lat"].ToString();
            Description = r["Description"].ToString();
            Address= r["Address"].ToString();
            string marker = "marker" + n.ToString();
            // create a line of JavaScript for marker on map for this record 
            Locations += Environment.NewLine + "var "+marker+@"=new GMarker(new GLatLng(" + Latitude + "," + Longitude + ")); map.addOverlay("+marker+@");";

            java += @"GEvent.addListener(" + marker + @", 'click', function() 
                    {
                        " + marker + @".openInfoWindowHtml('" + Description + @"');
                        map.checkResize();
                        map.setCenter(" + marker + @");
                    });";
            java2 += marker+@".openInfoWindowHtml('" + Description + @"');
                        map.checkResize();
                        map.setCenter("+marker+@");";

            n++;
        }

        // construct the final script
        js.Text =
            @"<script type='text/javascript'>
            function initialize() 
            {
                if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) 
                {
                    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),{ size: new GSize(350,300) } ); 
                    map.checkResize();
                    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(35.347769,-98.05),8); 
                    map.openInfoWindow(map.getCenter(), document.createTextNode('Hello')); 
                     " + Locations + java + @"


                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $('.dsc').css('cursor','pointer');
                        $('.dsc').each(function( intIndex ) {
                            $(this).bind ('click',function() {
                                 " + java2 + @"
                            });
                        });
                         });

                    map.setUIToDefault();
                }
            }
            </script> ";
    }
    protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string selectString = "SELECT Address, Description, Date, Lat, Long FROM D2_ReportAProblemForm ORDER BY id DESC";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectString, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);

        String Locations = "";
        String Description = "";
        String java2 = "";
        int n = 0;
        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            string Latitude = r["Long"].ToString();
            string Longitude = r["Lat"].ToString();
            Description = r["Description"].ToString();
            string marker = "marker" + n.ToString();
            // create a line of JavaScript for marker on map for this record 
            Locations += Environment.NewLine + "var " + marker + @"=new GMarker(new GLatLng(" + Latitude + "," + Longitude + ")); map.addOverlay(" + marker + @");";

            java2 += marker + @".openInfoWindowHtml('" + Description + @"');
                        map.checkResize();
                        map.setCenter(" + marker + @");";

            n++;
            js2.Text = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
                    {
                        $('.dsc').click(function()
                        {
                            " + java2 + @"
                    }
                    </script> ";
        }//end foreach



    }//end _DataBound

}
```

There are two `<asp:Literal>` with IDs `js` and `js2` so I can put jQuery/JavaScript right into the C# code.

GridView code:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    ondatabound="GridView1_DataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table width="500px">
                    <tr style="background-color: #dcdcdc;" >
                        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: left; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14xp;">
                        <asp:Label ID="Description" CssClass="dsc" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval ("Description") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="text-align: left; font-weight: lighter; font-size: 12px;">
                        <td>
                        <%#Eval ("Address") %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <%#Eval ("Date") %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

PLEASE help me figure this one out, I have been on this one part for a week and I am completely stumped. 
Thanks guys!

Comment: I see a contradiction in terms. _'the same description to each' ... 'uniquely'_ and _'have their own description'_. And what does _'there is are 2 with ids js and js2 so I can put jquery/javascript right into the c# code'_ even mean?

Comment: You've included a lot of code here, but the description doesn't provide enough information to tell us what behavior you're expecting, and what behavior you're getting instead.

Comment: Mr. Disappointment: 'the same description to each' meaning the same description that is shown if you click marker A or if you click Row A. Does that make sense? with the asp:Literal, I mean I have two asp:Literal controls, i believe they are called controls?, that I use to put my javascript code into. their ids are js and js2.

Comment: StriplingWarrior: What is happening is that when I click on any row in the GridView, the last description loaded from the database is showing above the markers. I have 2 rows in my data table, the first row has the description "Test" and the second row has the description "Test2". When I click on the row in the gridview that should have the description "Test" show, "Test2" shows. "Test2" also shows if you click on the other row in the gridview. Does that make sense?

Comment: You might want to include your gridview markup.  I suspect that the problem may lie there.

Comment: Chad, it has been added to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I see the problem.  You have this:

```
foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows){
...
   js2.Text = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
                    {
                        $('.dsc').click(function()
                        {
                            " + java2 + @"
                    }
                    </script> ";
}//end foreach
```

The problem is that each iteration of the loop is wiping out what you had done in the previous.  `js2.Text=` says set the text equal to this string, replacing what was already in it.

Now, issue #2.  Your jquery is as follows:

```
$('.dsc').click(function()
```

The problem here is that this will apply to every one of your rows since each one has the class dsc.  So even if you fix problem #1 by changing the text= to a text+=, your code will still not work.

You have 2 options that I can see.  First, you can assign a distinct ID to each label in addition to the class.  Then for each row your code could be `$('#myID1').click...`, where myID1 is a uniquely generated ID for each row.  Be careful if you do it this way as .net likes to generate big ugly IDs that aren't what you might think they will be.

The other option, and the one I would prefer is to just add the onclick directly to the label.  I think you should be able to just grab the label while in that foreach you have in your databound method.  Then you do something similar to this:

```
theLabel.Attributes.Add("onclick", java2);
```

May require some slight tweak to java2, I didn't look at it in full detail, but this way the onclick will just be attached directly to the label on initial load without any javascript to add it.